# How to run chrome devtools snippets for ReactJS application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

If I have to run the `stopBefore` snippet as in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/NV/5376464), how do I use it for ReactJS application?

The example shows for global object like `document`, but if I have to say stop before `ComponentX.SomeMethod`, how do I do it?

When trying

```
stopBefore(ComponentX,'SomeMethod')
```

It says, Uncaught ReferenceError: ComponentX is not defined

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> React components are not globally available.

Hence can't be accessed directly in the console.
But you can open Components tab in react-dev-tools than select the desired component and now open the console at the same time if not already using Esc key and type in $r in console to get the component's instance.

[image]

Now you can do whatever you desire-
`stopBefore($r, 'setState')`

As soon as you type
`$r.setState({})`
You will be taken to the debugger.